# How does streak.com create an integrated gmail experience?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, gmail-imap, browser-addons

[streak.com](http://www.streak.com/) is able to create a very rich experience integrated with gmail.  As far as I know, gmail doesn't allow plugins specifically.  How do they accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They built a [Google Chrome extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/) which injects HTML/JavaScript into the Gmail DOM.

Comment: I had to sign in with google oauth before streak started working, is that just a coincidence?

Comment: I assume they do that to get access to your emails for background processing. Otherwise they would have to scrape all the email data from the UI which would be very brittle.